# gdb: mac ctrl c make Terminal hanging

Tags: macos, gdb

My os is MACOS. When I debug the python source code with gdb --pid，I type the c, but I forget make a breakpoint, so i want to go back the gdb prompt with ctrl+c, but when i type ctrl+c, the terminal is hung, then i can't type anything. At last I have to close the terminal window, but it's ok with gdb program command. And then, I write a simple code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int num = 2;
    while(1){
        num ++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

then debug with gdb --pid, it's the same problem.

```
(gdb) c

Continuing.

^Cdarwin-nat.c:1356: internal-error: void darwin_interrupt(struct target_ops *, ptid_t): Assertion `!inf->priv->no_ptrace' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.

Quit this debugging session? (y or n)
```

Comment: This issue is occurring because interrupt handling on macOS is [currently unimplemented](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/master/gdb/darwin-nat.c#L1351). There's not much you can do other than wait for a fix.

Answer (score -3):

Try to use lldb . lldb is advised to use to debug code on OSX. Just let me know if lldb solves this problem

Comment: Thank you. Yes,  it works. Is there some method to solve the gdb problem, becase i was used to use gdb

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: yes, it didn't solve the problem directly, but give an another way

Comment: I've been finding ggdb on mac ports/high sierra + to be increasingly flaky - hanging etc... +1 for lldb as it actually works...